# How to program and use an ESP8266 module as a standalone device?

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I want to make an independent sensor which measures temperature and sends it to my NodeMCU. My ESP8266 module has two GPIO pins and that's enough for my temperature sensor.

I don't want to use an extra Arduino or some other board. I want to program my ESP8266 with my Arduino and then disconnect it from my Arduino, feed it with 3.3 V, and run it as a stand-alone device which sends temperature data to my NodeMCU.

Is this possible or do I need another board to operate the ESP8266?

Comment: Plenty of people programmed ESP8266. I'm not sure which software is needed (someone else will know) but it's very common.

Comment: PlatformIO would be my choice and there is an Arduino core for the esp8266,  so the learning curve should be low. There’s a project called Tasmota that will probably do what you want and much more without having to write a line of code.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need another board to operate the ESP8266 module. You do not even need another board to program it. The easiest way is to use the Arduino IDE to directly program the ESP8266 via USB cable. There are tons of guides on how to set that up - try [this one from randomnerdtutorials.](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/how-to-install-esp8266-board-arduino-ide/)

You can also  use the ESP-IDF, but that is certainly more complicated especially with the 8266.

Comment: It isn't possible "to directly program an ESP8266 via USB cable". Maybe you intended to say "USB-Serial cable", wasn't it? However, an USB-Serial cable is "another board". Although OP talks about a NodeMCU *and* an ESP8266 also, it seems that OP is not taking in account that NodeMCU module (which can be programmed via an simple USB cable) contains, by itself, an ESP8266). It seems that OP is talking about another ESP8266 module (ESP12, maybe). I suggest editing your answer, for clarity.